# Is there a JavaScript API to send logs to a cloud logging service (like papertrail)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, papertrail-app

I have some key events that are captured on the client side, and I would like to aggregate them easily. Instead of sending them to my server and pushing to [Papertrail](http://papertrailapp.com), is there any service out there that has a RESTful API to send logs? (or a JQuery plugin for Papertrail?)

Comment: Interesting, can you please elaborate a little more how it is done? e.g. how to customize the logging (e.g. error logging, log when user clicks a specific button, etc?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the quick rundown of Google Analytics event logging from their site:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Basically it breaks down to category, action[, label, value]. So for an error:

```
_gaq.push("_trackEvent", "error", "login", "bad password", 1);
```

For a button, e.g. slideshow:

```
_gaq.push("_trackEvent", "slideshow", "next");
```

Make sure to read the documentation, it does a better job than I do. You could also wire up try..catch events to Google Analytics and send the error code.

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed it... but that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: No problem - most people don't think to use GA beyond pageview logging, but it's pretty versatile. I used the event tracking a lot for determining which modules on a news page performed the best.

Comment: Learning this about the GA API made my morning. Thanks Mike!